# Organize files by date and put it into directories

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe

Is it possible to make something like this on Windows?
I have files which were created on different dates. For example:

```
test.txt   01.09.2015 11:56
test2.txt  04.11.2016 12:23
test3.txt  04.11.2016 12:24
.
.
.
test100.txt 02.02.2012 18:34
```

I want to put every file in a folder whose name is the creation date. For example:

```
move test.txt to folder "01.09.2015"
move test2.txt and test3.txt to folder "04.11.2016"
etc
```

Everything is in one dir.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I know how to create dir with current date
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a
mkdir %datestr%

Comment: There is an answer provided that will give you a full Powershell solution instead of a cmd solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go this way - Instead of comparing DateTime Objects, just use the `.toshortdatestring()` method:

```
$location = "C:\install"
gci $location -file | % { 
    $date = $_.creationtime.toshortdatestring()
    $fullpath = "$location\$date"
    if (!(Test-Path $fullpath)) { mkdir $fullpath }
    move-item $_.FullName $fullpath -Force
}
```

This will look for all files in `$location`, takes the creation-date of each object, `test-path`s if the folder already exists, if not it will create it, after that it will move the files to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you run this from the folder containing your files,

```
# get unique creation dates of files in the current working directory
$dates = Get-ChildItem * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CreationTime | Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy" | Sort-Object -Unique

foreach ($date in $dates) {
    # create directories based on the date
    New-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -ItemType Directory $date
}

# get each file's creation date
$files = Get-ChildItem -File

foreach ($file in $files) {
    # get the file's creation date (the folder to move to)
    $folder = $file | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CreationTime | Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"
    Move-Item $file $folder
}
```

Comment: But I want to make for each file separate dir take file with date 12.11.2016 11:45 and put it to dir 12.11.2016 11:45 another file 15.11.2015 and put it to dir 15.11.2015 etc

Comment: The above creates a folder for each unique creation date that exists and puts each file in the corresponding folder. It ignores the time.

Comment: It has created a dir called today's date and threw all files with diffrent dates into this dir

Comment: Then the creation date of your files is today. You can confirm this by running the first line of the script without defining it as a variable, `Get-ChildItem * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CreationTime | Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy" | Sort-Object -Unique`. This is likely due to you copying/moving the files, changing the creation date attribute.

Comment: Alternatively, you could replace `CreationTime` with `LastWriteTime` to use the modification date instead of creation date.

Answer (score 0):

[This GitHub project](https://github.com/deadlydog/MoveFilesIntoDateDirectories) does exactly what you're looking for, and will have the latest version of the code. Here's a derived PowerShell script that will do what you want:

```
[string] $SourceDirectoryPath = 'C:\FilesToMove'
[string] $TargetDirectoryPath = 'C:\SortedFiles'

[System.Collections.ArrayList] $filesToMove = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDirectoryPath -File -Force -Recurse

$filesToMove | ForEach-Object {
    [System.IO.FileInfo] $file = $_

    [DateTime] $fileDate = $file.LastWriteTime
    [string] $dateDirectoryName = $fileDate.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    [string] $dateDirectoryPath = Join-Path -Path $TargetDirectoryPath -ChildPath $dateDirectoryName

    if (!(Test-Path -Path $dateDirectoryPath -PathType Container))
    {
        Write-Verbose "Creating directory '$dateDirectoryPath'."
        New-Item -Path $dateDirectoryPath-ItemType Directory -Force > $null
    }

    [string] $filePath = $file.FullName
    Write-Information "Moving file '$filePath' into directory '$dateDirectoryPath'."
    Move-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $dateDirectoryPath
}
```

Note that it copies the file paths into an array before iterating over them. This is important for the cases where you are copying files to subdirectories of their current directory, otherwise `Get-ChildItem` could scan files twice, iterating over files that it just moved.